# Admin only version of transactional email?

Tags: transactional-mail

Is there a way to create a transactional email based on the customer's order that is sent to admins only? Basically I'm looking for one that I can edit with some other warehouse related empty spaces so when the guys pick the order, they have a place to write in some notes.

And it would send the admin account an email and the customer get's the typical one.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you asking if some one placed an order , than it should go to admin only ?

Comment: Your Question is not clear can you please explain it

Comment: No, not only. I'm basically wondering if Magento can send a copy to an admin using a different template than what the customer will receive.

Answer (score 0):

There is no buit-in ability to disable particular email notifications in Magento. I suggest you to look at the **Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::sendTransactional** method. You can overload this class and add check against allowed/disallowed email notifications (based on template name).

Update: you can use [free extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/12837/s/disable-email-notifications-8993/) for disabling specific email notifications in Magento.

Comment: Well more like:

"new order template" goes to customer
"new order template for admin" goes to me - so nothing disabled just more.

Comment: @Daniel Please accept the answer if it worked for you.